# Is there a limit to how many Akka Streams can run at the same time?

Tags: scala, akka, scalability, akka-stream

I am trying to implement a simple one-to-many pub/sub pattern using a `BroadcastHub`. This fails silently for large numbers of subscribers, which makes me think I am hitting some limit on the number of streams I can run.

First, let's define some events:

```scala
sealed trait Event
case object EX extends Event
case object E1 extends Event
case object E2 extends Event
case object E3 extends Event
case object E4 extends Event
case object E5 extends Event
```

I have implemented the publisher using a `BroadcastHub`, adding a `Sink.actorRefWithAck` each time I want to add a new subscriber. Publishing the `EX` event ends the broadcast:

```scala
trait Publisher extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  private val sourceQueue = Source.queue[Event](Publisher.bufferSize, Publisher.overflowStrategy)
  private val (
    queue: SourceQueueWithComplete[Event],
    source: Source[Event, NotUsed]
  ) = {
    val (q,s) = sourceQueue.toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 256))(Keep.both).run()
    s.runWith(Sink.ignore)
    (q,s)
  }

  def publish(evt: Event) = {
    log.debug("Publishing Event: {}", evt.getClass().toString())
    queue.offer(evt)
    evt match {
      case EX => queue.complete()
      case _ => Unit
    }
 }

  def subscribe(actor: ActorRef, ack: ActorRef): Unit =
    source.runWith(
      Sink.actorRefWithAck(
        actor,
        onInitMessage = Publisher.StreamInit(ack),
        ackMessage = Publisher.StreamAck,
        onCompleteMessage = Publisher.StreamDone,
        onFailureMessage = onErrorMessage))

  def onErrorMessage(ex: Throwable) = Publisher.StreamFail(ex)

  def publisherBehaviour: Receive = {
    case Publisher.Subscribe(sub, ack) => subscribe(sub, ack.getOrElse(sender()))
    case Publisher.StreamAck => Unit
  }

  override def receive = LoggingReceive { publisherBehaviour }
}

object Publisher {
  final val bufferSize = 5
  final val overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.backpressure

  case class Subscribe(sub: ActorRef, ack: Option[ActorRef])

  case object StreamAck
  case class StreamInit(ack: ActorRef)
  case object StreamDone
  case class StreamFail(ex: Throwable)
}
```

Subscribers can implement the `Subscriber` trait to separate the logic:

```scala
trait Subscriber {
  def onInit(publisher: ActorRef): Unit = ()
  def onInit(publisher: ActorRef, k: KillSwitch): Unit = onInit(publisher)
  def onEvent(event: Event): Unit = ()
  def onDone(publisher: ActorRef, subscriber: ActorRef): Unit = ()
  def onFail(e: Throwable, publisher: ActorRef, subscriber: ActorRef): Unit = ()
}
```

The actor logic is quite simple:

```scala
class SubscriberActor(subscriber: Subscriber) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  def subscriberBehaviour: Receive = {
    case Publisher.StreamInit(ack) => {
      log.debug("Stream initialized.")
      subscriber.onInit(sender())
      sender() ! Publisher.StreamAck
      ack.forward(Publisher.StreamInit(ack))
    }
    case Publisher.StreamDone => {
      log.debug("Stream completed.")
      subscriber.onDone(sender(),self)
    }
    case Publisher.StreamFail(ex) => {
      log.error(ex, "Stream failed!")
      subscriber.onFail(ex,sender(),self)
    }
    case e: Event => {
      log.debug("Observing Event: {}",e)
      subscriber.onEvent(e)
      sender() ! Publisher.StreamAck
    }
  }

  override def receive = LoggingReceive { subscriberBehaviour }
}
```

One of the key points is that all subscribers must receive all messages sent by the publisher, so we have to know that all streams have materialized and all actors are ready to receive before starting the broadcast. This is why the `StreamInit` message is forwarded to another, user-provided actor.

To test this, I define a simple `MockPublisher` that just broadcasts a list of events when told to do so:

```scala
class MockPublisher(events: Event*) extends Publisher {
  def receiveBehaviour: Receive = {
    case MockPublish => events map publish
  }
  override def receive = LoggingReceive { receiveBehaviour orElse publisherBehaviour }
}
case object MockPublish
```

I also define a `MockSubscriber` who merely counts how many events it has seen:

```scala
class MockSubscriber extends Subscriber {
  var count = 0
  val promise = Promise[Int]()
  def future = promise.future

  override def onInit(publisher: ActorRef): Unit = count = 0
  override def onEvent(event: Event): Unit = count += 1
  override def onDone(publisher: ActorRef, subscriber: ActorRef): Unit = promise.success(count)
  override def onFail(e: Throwable, publisher: ActorRef, subscriber: ActorRef): Unit = promise.failure(e) 
}
```

And a small method for subscription:

```scala
object MockSubscriber {
  def sub(publisher: ActorRef, ack: ActorRef)(implicit system: ActorSystem): Future[Int] = {
    val s = new MockSubscriber()
    implicit val tOut = Timeout(1.minute)
    val a = system.actorOf(Props(new SubscriberActor(s)))

    val f = publisher ! Publisher.Subscribe(a, Some(ack))

    s.future
  }
}
```

I put everything together in a unit test:

```scala
class SubscriberTests extends TestKit(ActorSystem("SubscriberTests")) with
    WordSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll with ImplicitSender {

  override def beforeAll:Unit = {
    system.eventStream.setLogLevel(Logging.DebugLevel)
  }
  override def afterAll:Unit = {
    println("Shutting down...")
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }

  "The Subscriber" must {
    "publish events to many observers" in {
      val n = 9

      val p = system.actorOf(Props(new MockPublisher(E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,EX)))

      val q = scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Future[Int]]()

      for (i <- 1 to n) {
        q += MockSubscriber.sub(p,self)
      }

      for (i <- 1 to n) {
        expectMsgType[Publisher.StreamInit](70.seconds)
      }
      p ! MockPublish

      q.map { f => Await.result(f, 10.seconds) should be (6) }
    }
  }
}
```

This test succeeds for relatively small values of `n`, but fails for, say, `val n = 90000`. No caught or uncaught exception appears anywhere and neither does any out-of-memory complaint from Java (which does occur if I go even higher).

What am I missing?

Edit: Tried this on multiple computers with different specs. Debug info shows no messages reach any of the subscribers once `n` is high enough.

Answer (score 0):

Akka Stream (and any other reactive stream, actually) provides you backpressure. If you hadn't messed up with how you create your consumers (e.g. allowing creation of 1GB JSON, which will you chop into smaller pieces only after you fetched it into memory) you should have a comfortable situation where you can consider your memory usage pretty much upper-bounded (because of how backpressure manage push-pull mechanics). Once you measure where your upper-bound lies, your can set up your JVM and container memory, so that you could let it run without fear of out of memory errors (provided that there is not other thing happening in your JVM which could cause memory usage spike).

So, from this we can see that there is some constraint on how much stream you can run in parallel - specifically you can run only as much of them as your memory allows you. CPU should not be a limitation (as you will have multiple threads), but if you will start too much of them on one machine, then CPU inevitably with have to switch between different streams making each of them slower. It might not be a technical blocker, but you might end up in a situation where processing is so slow that it doesn't fulfill its business purpose (though, I guess, you would have to run much more than few of streams at once).

In your tests you might run into some other issues as well. E.g. if you reuse the same thread pool for some blocking operations as you use for Actor System without informing the thread pool that they are blocking, you might end up with a dead lock (as a matter of the fact, you should run all IO blocking operations on a different thread pool than "computing" operations). Having 90000(!) concurrent things happening at the same time (and probably having the same small thread pool) almost guarantees running into issues (I guess you could run into issues even if instead of actors you would run the code directly on futures). Here you are using actor system in tests, which AFAIR use blocking logic only highlighting all the possible issues with small thread pools which keep blocking and non-blocking tasks in the same place.

Comment: If I am running out of VM memory, this is happening silently which makes it an issue with Akka Streams. Increasing the number of streams further does get me an `OutOfMemoryError`, but that is expected. The code above gets stuck with no exception showing. 
Also, other than waiting for the final results in the main thread, there is no other blocking or efficiency bottleneck in the code I posted.

Comment: It's unrelated to the question in title, but you have several sinks reading from the same queue e.g. Sing.ignore in `s.runWith(Sink.ignore)` - it might be reading events from queue before all the other streams (you share queue across streams...) so all the other ones might never receive an event.

Comment: The source is a `BroadcastHub`, which allows you to materialize the source several times. See: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#using-the-broadcasthub